# Using Ant to remove sections from a manifest file (unsigning JARs)

Tags: ant, jar

**Context of problem**

I am trying to write a bit of ant to unsign a JAR. In order to do this, I am trying to make the following 2 changes to an existing signed JAR file:

1. Remove META-INF/*SF, META-INF/*.DSA and META-INF/*.RSA files from the JAR
2. Remove signature related sections from the JAR's manifest

I can remove the signature related files using the zip and zipfileset tasks, however, I am struggling to edit the manifest file to remove signature sections.

**Problem to solve**

I need an **automated way using Ant** to create or edit a manifest file which originally looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Application-Name: My Application
Class-Path: lib/my-jar-one.jar lib/my-jar-two.jar
Built-By: Developer Name

Name: org/mycompany/myapplication/MyApplicationClassOne.class
SHA1-Digest: dsaf89y342t24grg9grn90gh24g

Name: org/mycompany/myapplication/MyApplicationClassTwo.class
SHA1-Digest: sdfgviuonw0423t42h9brbr4
```

into this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Application-Name: My Application
Class-Path: lib/my-jar-one.jar lib/my-jar-two.jar
Built-By: Developer Name
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have been searching online in various ways, but I cannot find a solution to solving this problem

**Additional Scenario**

Some lines continue onto the next line, such as in the following manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Application-Name: My Application
Class-Path: lib/my-jar-one.jar lib/my-jar-two.jar
Built-By: Developer Name

Name: org/mycompany/myapplication/blah/blah/blah/MyApplicationClassOne
 .class
SHA1-Digest: dsaf89y342t24grg9grn90gh24g

Name: org/mycompany/myapplication/MyApplicationClassTwo.class
SHA1-Digest: sdfgviuonw0423t42h9brbr4
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I got working for this problem is as follows:

```
<copy file="MANIFEST.MF" tofile="MANIFEST.MF.EDITED" overwrite="true">
    <filterchain>
        <replaceregex pattern="\nName:(.+?)\nSH" replace="SH" flags="gis" byline="false"/>
        <replaceregex pattern="SHA1-Digest:.*" replace="" flags="gis" byline="false"/>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

This seems to work although I have got this working by trial and error and do not fully understand the solution in place. If somebody could clarify, it would be very helpful

Comment: gis stands for: global, case insensitive, multi-line

Comment: The first search "wraps" to the next line and only matches if the next line starts with "SH" leaving "SH" in place (replace="SH"). Note that the next line could also be "SHA-256-Digest" so the above routine would not match that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [FilterChain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html)s to achieve this. For instance, code below will copy an original MANIFEST file skipping the lines you wanted to remove:

```
<copy file="MANIFEST.MF.ORIGIN" tofile="MANIFEST.MF" overwrite="true">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp negate="true">
            <regexp pattern="^Name:.*$"/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
        <linecontainsregexp negate="true">
            <regexp pattern="^SHA1-Digest:.*$"/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: This is great, although some lines are greater than 72 characters and so the Name: attributes extends onto the next line which the above solution does not capture. I have edited my original post to include this scenario

Comment: Perhaps a filter chain that uses a line tokenizer and stops copying content when the first blank line is found? Apologies, I am not too familiar with ant scripting and so a simple problem can take time to solve. The help is very much appreciated